# Escaping characters with ajax and ColdFusion

Tags: ajax, encoding, coldfusion

Hello I've got an issue with an encode failing.  Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong?

```
<form>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="background-color:#ededed;padding:50px;">
        <tr>
            <td align="left"><b>Screen? (eg. Index)</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left"><input type="text" name="strFeedbackScreen" value="" style="width:300px;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="height:10px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left"><b>Comments:</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left"><textarea name="strFeedbackComments" style="width:400px;height:150px;"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="height:10px"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="left"><b>Thank you for your feedback.</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="height:10px"></td>
        </tr>

        <cfoutput>

            <tr>
                <td align="left"><input type="button" value="Send" class="button" 
                    onMouseover="this.className = 'buttonover';" 
                    onMousedown="this.className = 'buttonover';" 
                    onMouseOut="this.className = 'button';" 
                    onclick="sendfeedback('strFeedbackScreen='+escape(this.form.strFeedbackScreen.value)+',strFeedbackComments='+escape(this.form.strFeedbackComments.value),'send_feedback_action_ajax')">
                </td>
            </tr>

        </cfoutput>

    </table>
</form>
```

is the form

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfmail to="feedback@example.com" from="feedback@example.com" subject="Feedback left" type="html">

        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>**** This email has been sent to all concerned ****</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height:10px;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <cfif application.ds eq "App1">
                <tr>
                    <td>This feedback has been left on App 1.</td>
                </tr>
            <cfelseif application.ds eq "App2">
                <tr>
                    <td>This feedback has been left on App 2.</td>
                </tr>
            <cfelseif application.ds eq "App3">
                <tr>
                    <td>This feedback has been left on App 3.</td>
                </tr>
            </cfif>

            <tr>
                <td style="height:10px;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>From:</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>#session.stafffirstname# #session.staffsurname# - #session.staffemail#</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height:10px;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Screen:</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>#strFeedbackScreen#</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height:10px;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Comments:</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>#strFeedbackComments#</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </cfmail>
</cfoutput>
```

is the action.cfm

and the javascript is

```
function sendfeedback(fields,action) { 
    turnLayeron('ajaxloading');
    nocache = Math.random();
    http.open('get', '/ajax.cfm?action='+action+'&fields='+fields+'&nocache='+nocache);
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4){
        closepopout();  
            turnLayeroff('ajaxloading');
        }
    };
    http.send(null);
}
```

I've been trying to get uriencode working, but it encodes my string before it gets emailed.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what error you're experiencing and where?

Comment: if the strfeedbackcomments contains an illegal character, nothing after that character is passed on.

Comment: What's the issue with URLEncoding it and then Decoding it when you want to display it?

Comment: can you alert the second argument to the http.open() function and check if it has any question marks or ampersands?
The escape() function should ensure that you dont have any ? or & in your string. Passing any of these in a GET will mess up your request.

As an aside, to save data to the server it is preferable to use a POST, not a GET.

Answer (score 2):

Change your JavaScript to following:

```
function sendfeedback(fields,action) {
    http.open("POST", '/ajax.cfm?action='+action+'&nocache='+nocache, true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(http.readyState == 4){
            closepopout();  
            turnLayeroff('ajaxloading');
        }
    };
    http.send(fields);
}
```

Also change your function call to:

`onclick="sendfeedback('strFeedbackScreen='+escape(this.form.strFeedbackScreen.value)+'&strFeedbackComments='+escape(this.form.strFeedbackComments.value),'send_feedback_action_ajax')"`

Comment: I'd rather a more thorough solution than just escaping.  Can I simply replace escape with urlencode?

Comment: Where would you call urlEncode()? There is no coldfusion processing between someone pressing submit button and ajax call. escape() is the way to go. You only escape it for the post btw. In the email your characters will be correct.  There is no need for urlEncode() in your scenario.

Comment: Also in your original code I think onclick should read: 

`onclick="sendfeedback('strFeedbackScreen='+escape(this.form.strFeedbackScreen.value)+'&strFeedbackComments='+escape(this.form.strFeedbackComments.value),'send_feedback_action_ajax')`

with "&" instead of ","